# Is it better to declare the DataType of a function?

Tags: vb.net

In VB .NET, What is the difference between declaring the functions's data type and ignoring it, i mean is it declared as an Object like the Variables or like something else? to be clearer which function of these two is better:

```
Private Function foo(ByVal text As String)
    Return text
End Function


Private Function foo2(ByVal text As String) As String
    Return text
End Function
```

Does the first one declared "As Object"? and if so, that means the second one in better, right?

Answer (score 3):

The second is clearly better, the first exists only for backwards compatibility reasons. It is only allowed with [`Option Strict`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to `Off` which is **not recommended** anyway.

This is the [compiler error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44h6ck64.aspx) you normally get:

> Option Strict On requires all Function, Property, and Operator
>   declarations to have an 'As' clause

The return type is `Object` for the first.

Comment: Right i tried that out, it seems like the Option Strict was Off in default. that's all i need.

Comment: @IOS: unfortunately `Off` it's still the default value. You should change it to make "On" the default project setting in visual studio.

Comment: Yeah! that sounds better than putting the Option Strict On in each class. appreciate your advice

Comment: @IOS: remember to accept the answer if your question is answered ;)